# How to get a subform field value?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access form with (continuous) subform and one of the combobox fields on the subform is populated with data depending on the value of another field.
For this I use the following in the Data Row Source:

```
    SELECT VendorName FROM VendorsPerAction WHERE (Action= Forms![LocalSubformActions]![fldAction]) UNION SELECT distinct null FROM VendorsPerAction ORDER BY VendorName;
```

This works fine when I test the form outside the mainform. But when I test this as part of the mainform Access keeps asking me for the parameter. I tried changing it into:

```
    (Action= Forms![LocalRequest].[LocalSubformActions]![fldAction])
```

and many other variations but I keep getting the parameter question.

Is there anyone who knows what I should use? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably

```
Forms![LocalRequest].[LocalSubformActions].Form![fldAction]
```

(assuming the subform control has the same name as the subform)

See [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

--> `Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName`

Comment: Unfortunately this one also doesn't work. <br>LocalRequest is the main form, LocalSubformActions is the (contineous) subform, fldAction is the field I need to query.

Comment: You need to check the name of the **subform control**. Open the main form in design view, single-click (!) the subform, open properties.

Comment: Gosh I feel soooo stupid now! You were right! changed it to "SELECT VendorName FROM VendorsPerAction WHERE (Action= Forms![LocalRequest].[subfActions].Form![fldAction]) UNION SELECT distinct null FROM VendorsPerAction ORDER BY VendorName;" and works perfectly. Many thanks!